# Opening multiple fonts with PIL.ImageFont.truetype() causes OSError

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have some code that is supposed to open a font in multiple sizes:

```
from PIL import ImageFont

INTER_BOLD_48 = ImageFont.truetype("assets/Inter-Bold.ttf", 48)
INTER_BOLD_36 = ImageFont.truetype("assets/Inter-Bold.tff", 36)
INTER_BOLD_28 = ImageFont.truetype("assets/Inter-Bold.tff", 28)

# more fonts get opened below, but it never makes it there
```

However, this throws the error `OSError: cannot open resource`
Full error:

```
  File "/home/lazza/PycharmProjects/YippyBot/tests.py", line 4, in <module>
    INTER_BOLD_36 = ImageFont.truetype("assets/Inter-Bold.tff", 36)
  File "/home/lazza/PycharmProjects/YippyBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 1008, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
  File "/home/lazza/PycharmProjects/YippyBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 1005, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/home/lazza/PycharmProjects/YippyBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 255, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(
OSError: cannot open resource
```

From the error I realised that the first font opening was running fine.
So I tried changing the font size in the argument to see if setting it to 36 was the problem:

```
from PIL import ImageFont

INTER_BOLD_48 = ImageFont.truetype("assets/Inter-Bold.ttf", 36)
INTER_BOLD_36 = ImageFont.truetype("assets/Inter-Bold.tff", 36)
INTER_BOLD_28 = ImageFont.truetype("assets/Inter-Bold.tff", 28)
```

But the error is exactly the same:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lazza/PycharmProjects/YippyBot/tests.py", line 4, in <module>
    INTER_BOLD_36 = ImageFont.truetype("assets/Inter-Bold.tff", 36)
  File "/home/lazza/PycharmProjects/YippyBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 1008, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
  File "/home/lazza/PycharmProjects/YippyBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 1005, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/home/lazza/PycharmProjects/YippyBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 255, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(
OSError: cannot open resource
```

So I figured maybe opening the same font twice was causing the problem and so commented the first line out:

```
# INTER_BOLD_48 = ImageFont.truetype("assets/Inter-Bold.ttf", 48)
INTER_BOLD_36 = ImageFont.truetype("assets/Inter-Bold.tff", 36)
```

Same error. I also tried duplicating the .ttf files and giving each font a unique name, as well as giving the full path to the font.

I am on Linux, but I don't see why that would be a problem as I provide the path to the font.

Comment: Try creating an issues with the repo https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues

Comment: This is just a typo: .tff instead of .ttf for the extension.